# Set extent of all maps in a layout to a single map ArcGIS Pro

Tags: dictionary, arcgis, extent

I am making a series of maps that I want to all show the exact same extent. I thought I could set the extent for each map to the same values by doing the following:

1. activate map1
2. navigate to the extent I want
3. deactivate map1
4. Rclick on map1, choose properties, extent tab, use a custom
   extent, use "COPY all extent values" button
5. Rclick on mapN,
   choose properties, extent tab, use a custom extent, use "PASTE all
   extent values" button
6. click OK

However, the extent values from map1 are not pasted into the extent fields of map2, so after clicking OK, nothing changes. I have tried doing this with the map "activated" and with "activation" closed. Neither works.

Is this a bug or am I missing something. Currently my only option seems to be manually copying and pasting the 4 extent values to each map... ouch!

Is there an option to have ALL maps in a single layout have the same extent? If not, there should be! That way each map can easily display the same extent after changing the extent in single map, adding or removing data, etc.

I am using ArcGIS pro 2.4.1 on a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe that "bookmarks" is what you are looking for.

1. Set the extent of one of the map frames to that which you desire by activating the frame.
2. navigate to ribbon and from "bookmarks", create new bookmark.
3. Now go and activate the other map frames which you want to be that same extent, go to bookmarks, and select the bookmark that you just created. Both frames will now be the same extent.

Below is an example of the result. Let me know if this is what you meant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was R clicking on the map, rather than the map frame. So this works (Rclick on the map frame either in the Contents panel or the layout view, choose properties, go to Display Options tab):

[image]

But this doesn't (Rclick on the map in the contents panel, choose properties, go to extent, use custom extent):

[image]

I am still looking for a way to link the extents of all map frames in a layout.